# How to display message in php without using alert or confirm?

Tags: php

I want to show the changes made in current file after submitting form as message without alert and confirm.How can I do this?

I update language with:

```
$query="update `account_detail` set `prompt_language`= '$language' WHERE `org_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
$Msg="updated language to $language";

      function logToFile($filename, $msg)
      { 
      $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
      $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg; 
      fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
      fclose($fd);
      }

      logToFile("change.log", "updated language to $language");


      header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");
```

I put all cheanges made in file.And also want to show as message.

Comment: Just echo it out to the page?

Comment: `alert` and `confirm` are not functions of PHP that is unless you made them yourself. As said you can use `echo`.

Comment: What kind of message? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: add your code for better understand.

Comment: @soni8010 use [JQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: get the updated data from php and after submit write it to a message section of your page.

Comment: @Criesto.I use Dialog.But it works only if I remove header() form my code.But I want to redirect this page.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
<?PHP 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['something']))
    {
        echo('you made some changes...');
    }
    else
    { ?>

        <form method="POST">
            <input name="something" type="text" />
            <!-- rest of code here... -->
            <button type="submit">
        </form>

<?PHP 
    } 
?>
```

The logic being, if the variable has been set (*i.e. the form has been submitted*) then echo out a message to the page, othewise display the form.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

**your view page:**

```
<body>
<div id="message"><?PHP 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']))
    {
        echo $_REQUEST['msg'];
    }
?>
</div>
        <form method="POST" action="submit.php">
            <input name="language" type="text" />
            <!-- rest of code here... -->
            <button type="submit" >SUBMIT</button>
        </form>

</body>
```

**your submit.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['language'])){
    $msg=array();

    $language=$_POST['language'];
    $Msg="updated language to $language";

    logToFile("change.log", "updated language to $language");
    ////yor rest pf the code

    header("location:view1.php?view=view_service&msg=".$Msg);
}


function logToFile($filename, $msg)
{
    $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
    $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg;
    fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
}

?>
```